# Azure AD 'generic' settings for users, devices

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

There are some default settings for devices in Azure AD: 
- Users may join devices to Azure AD (All-Selected-none)
- Additional local administrators on Azure AD joined devices (Selected-None)
- Require Multi-Factor Auth to join devices
an so on.

I am not able to find any solution to do this PROGRAMMATICALLY.

I went thru all MS Graph (also beta), tried PowerShell - Azure AD, Exchange Online, but without any result.

Only Msol has cmdlet Set-MsolDeviceRegistratioinServicePolicy, which does the job. But not whole job - I can't find how to set users/groups which can be selected.

And anyway, does MS Graph have this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

MS Graph doesn't have this functionality yet. All the operations of Device are list here. Currently we can manage device identity [using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/device-management-azure-portal). You can send your feedback regarding this at the bottom of this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/device-management-azure-portal). Hope it helps.

[image]